# Set AppUserModelID for a window

Tags: c#, winapi

To set an AppUserModelID for the whole process, I can use [`SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378422). How do I set the AppUserModelID for an individual window?  I am using C#, but I am open to a native Win32 solution as long as I have something that works.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120820-00/?p=6813

Comment: Per-window: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110601-00/?p=10523/

Comment: Thank you. Jonathan's link provided the info. If you write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Valid link for "per window" – [How do I prevent users from pinning my program to the taskbar?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110601-00/?p=10523)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [MSDN blog link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110601-00/?p=10523/) provided by Jonathan Potter, need to use COM in native code

```
 IPropertyStore *pps;
 HRESULT hr = SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow(hwnd, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pps));
 if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
  PROPVARIANT var;
  // ... set up PROPVARIANT to contain AppUserModelID string
  hr = pps->SetValue(PKEY_AppUserModel_ID, var);
  pps->Release();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it in C#

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern void SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID( [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string AppID);
```

Then, in the constructor for your application's main window, or some other code that is run before any UI elements are created:

```
SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID("MyCompany.MyApp.Version");
```

Note that the AppId string should be the same for all applications that you want grouped together.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908976/are-aumids-application-user-model-ids-unique says an AUMID should have an exclamation point. If that's true, can we add `!App` to your example `"MyCompany.MyApp.Version"` AUMID string so it's more realistic looking?

Comment: @paulie4 - thanks, I didn't know that. Should it be "MyCompany!MyApp.Version" ?

Comment: You can run `Get-StartApps` in PowerShell and see all the different ones that are installed on your system. Some of them do have periods to the right of the `!`, but most don't. Oh, but a lot of them also *don't* have `!`, so I guess it's not necessary?

Comment: Is it possible to set an external process AppID started with C# Process p = ... ?

Comment: @ScottKramer - I'm not sure what you mean. You can set your AppID to the same as another process, but this method only affects the current process. You can't use it to change the AppID of another process.